# iOS parse specific jSON

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I meet a problem to parse a jSON, I've a jSON like that :

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "message": "ok"
}
```

I tried several things to try to get the value of "id", and "message", but I've always an error..

How can I do to pick the value of "id", and "message" please ?

(I get the result of my `JSON` in a `NSMutableArray`)

**EDIT** :

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSMutableDictionary *publicTimeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:publicTimeline.allKeys];
[sortedArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
return sortedArray;
```

Comment: The JSON you provided is in the form of `NSDictionary`. Parse the JSON to `NSDictionary` and use `[responseDictionary valueForKey:@"message"]`

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: I'm using this to execute the webservice and get the jSON :

I edited my post.

Comment: Is the above JSON sample is the full response or partial?

Comment: for this case, is the full response

Comment: What is the error and where you try to take value from response parsed dictionary?

Comment: The dictionary returned by NSJSONSerialization is, by default, non-mutable, as would be any NSArray contained in it (which there isn't in this case).

Comment: (And you only get the "result of your JSON in an NSMutableArray" through some rather silly manipulations.  The JSON is an "object", which corresponds to an NSDictionary -- there is no array anywhere.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON string represents a dictionary. So you have to use `NSDictionary` instead of `NSArray`.

**EDIT I**

```
// convert dictionary into JSON
NSDictionary *fromDict = @{@"id": @(0), @"message": @"ok"};
NSData *JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:fromDict options:0 error:nil];

// convert data (like you get from an API request) to dictionary
NSDictionary *toDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:0 error:nil];
```

Comment: I tried to convert my NSMutableArray to NSData, but, the logs shows me "null" for id and message :/

Comment: @develost You don't need to convert anything to NSData and the array in your code is only giving you the keys from the dictionary. As all of the answers are showing you, you can just get the two values straight from the dictionary return by the JSON parser

Comment: @deveLost - You are lost -- no doubt about that.

Comment: @deveLost: does your edit now works with my correction?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Parse the JSON response to `NSDictionary`

```
NSDictionary * responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSString *message = [responseDictionary valueForKey:@"message"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its helpful to you (In this response you get first dictionary and dictionary contains two key.so   )

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSDictionary *publicTimeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

NSString *message = [publicTimeline valueForKey:@"message"];
```

I Think it useful link for you. [json parser](https://sites.google.com/site/99classroomdiscussion/assignments/json-parsar)

Comment: It's not an NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: What is returned by NSJSONSerialization (with no options) is an NSDictionary, not an NSMutableDictionary.  You cannot use an NSDictionary as if it were an NSMutableDictionary.